# How to install xmlrpclib in python 3.4?

Tags: python, xml-rpc, python-3.4, xmlrpclib, xmlrpcclient

When I am trying to install xmlrpclib, I am getting following error in python version 3.4

Downloading/unpacking xmlrpclib
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement xmlrpclib
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external xmlrpclib to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for xmlrpclib
Storing debug log for failure in /home/shiva/.pip/pip.log

How to install xmlrpclib in python 3.4 ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`xmlrpclib` is part of the standard library in Python 2.x. It's not a package that you need to install.

In Python 3.x you can import it from `xmlrpc` instead: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.html. You can import the client from `xmlrpc.client`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.client.html#module-xmlrpc.client.

Answer (score 5):

import xmlrpc.client as xc

```
enter code hereenter code here
client = xc.Server('http://' + host + ':' + port + '/RPC2')
client.supervisor.getState()
client.supervisor.getProcessInfo('process name')
```