# Cuckoo xmlrpclib missing while uploading file

Tags: python, xmlrpclib

I recently set up Cuckoo environment on Arch Linux host with WXPSP3 guest.

When I try to upload file for analysis using submit.py I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./utils/submit.py", line 23, in <module>
    from lib.cuckoo.common.utils import to_unicode
  File "/opt/cuckoo/utils/../lib/cuckoo/common/utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    import xmlrpclib
ImportError: No module named 'xmlrpclib'
```

I run out of ideas. Could you help?

J

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134362/python-install-xmlrpclib, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676943/how-to-install-xmlrpclib-in-python-3-4

Comment: Thanks. I have seen that before, but I solved it different way. Just goto app main dir /opt/cuckoo/ and run submit.py using python2.7 command :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I run python via python2.7 command so:

```
# python2.7 ./utils/submit.py <filepath>
```